# Determine if type reference is nullable/non-nullable

Tags: c#, c#-8.0, nullable-reference-types

Using the upcoming C# 8 nullable reference type feature, how can I tell if the type signature for a field/method/ property etc is a nullable or non-nullable reference type at runtime?

Comment: Roslyn isn't the right tool for runtime inspection. You're looking for [Reflection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection?view=netframework-4.7.1).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to detect whether a type can be nullable at runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56705694/how-to-detect-whether-a-type-can-be-nullable-at-runtime)

Answer (score 1):

In runtime you should be able to check that by checking custom attributes. This is how current prototype captures this information. But I guess until it's released something can still change.
Take a look at answer to [this](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/36#issuecomment-422685949) question in official C# language design repo provided by yaakov.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think you can.

The way I read it, it is totally a compile time thing.

I.e. refclass = not nullable, refclass? = nullable and the compiler makes sure that at compile time this is checked.

Runtime "doesn ot care" - the class doesn not change. I can convert nullable to non nullable by means of a null check, and the compiler will be happy.

Comment: Do they not even put a custom attribute? EDIT: If one assembly uses a DLL created by an earlier compilation, would they not want to have a way to "signal" that a parameter type is non-nullable?