# How to detect whether a type can be nullable at runtime?

Tags: c#, c#-8.0, nullable-reference-types

I'm trying to detect whether a type can be nullable or not at runtime to convert that type to the corresponding GraphQL type so that, for example:

With nullable reference types **enabled**:

- `string` is converted to `String!`
- `string?` is converted to `String`

With nullable reference types **disabled**:

- `string` is converted to `String`
- `NonNull<string>` is converted to `String!` (`NonNull` is a custom library type)

I'm having trouble adapting the code that detected the nullability of a type:

```
bool isNullable = !typeInfo.IsValueType;
```

How can I change it so that it works with nullable reference types both enabled and disabled?

Comment: What you mean is check whether a field, property, method return value or method parameter is nullable or not, including support for nullable reference types?

Comment: Just determining if a type (as in `TypeInfo` for example) accepts `null`.

Comment: I ask because contrary to the name of the new support, this isn't really about the *type*, but more about the *thing* that has that type. In other words, this new support is attached to the property (as an example), but not the type of the property.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen I'm confused. Why would they choose to go with that?

Comment: The new support is done using attributes, and they are attached to the members or parameters, not to the types of those, so if you find a field using FieldInfo, and then check the FieldInfo.FieldType, that `Type` object will not know that the field has been configured to be non-nullable.

Comment: If they had changed the `Type` object to reflect this, almost all existing code would have to be rewritten to handle nullable/non-nullable reference types. With the attribute change, the existing reflection code will still get the same Type objects it always has, but be oblivious to the presence of this new information.

Comment: For instance, you would then have 2 Type objects for System.String, one for nullable and one for non-nullable. Existing code would have to cope with this. They chose a different route.

Comment: Bear in mind that if you enable this support, by default all *existing* code will behave as though you do not want nullable reference type values, you have to opt-back-out by allowing nullable values being used, and this ends up as a `[Nullable(...)]` attribute being attached to the field, property, method return value or method parameter. The `(...)` can be omitted if the attribute only refers to the thing it is applied to, but for generic types there is a flattened list of parameters specifying the nullability for each flattened item.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen I see. If you explain that briefly in an answer and maybe show ways to check whether a field, property, method return value or method parameter is nullable or not I'll accept the answer.

Comment: I could do that, but I don't really have the time for that kind of spelunking right now. Additionally, I still believe there is a good duplicate here on Stack Overflow for this so I would also like to take some time first to see if that is true.

Comment: I can't seem to find any though, been trying a few times while writing comments here. Let me write up the start of an answer and we'll see how far off the deep end I get :)

Comment: OK, answer is up, no doubt I have missed something as I haven't really used this kind of code that much, I don't have room for virtual machines and so on so I'm trying to avoid installing too much beta-software on my development machines. LINQPad is rather safe to play with though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that there are good ways to check for "the old" nullable types that applies to value types that is documented thoroughly here on Stack Overflow.

I will then instead only focus on nullable *reference* types, and provide the means to check if one of those are in effect.

Let me sum up my comments on the question first as they are rather important.

Contrary to the name of the new feature, nullable reference *types* is not about the *types*, but rather about the *things* these types are used for. These *things* are:

- Fields
- Properties
- Method return values
- Method parameters

Now, of course this also applies to local variables but you need a whole 'nother kind of introspection to deal with decoding instructions. I do not know how, or even if, this kind of information is encoded in the actual instructions for local variables.

OK, so with that out of the way, let's look at some code (btw, I'm using [LINQPad](https://linqpad.net) with Roslyn experimental mode to test all this):

```
public string? Nullable;
public string NonNullable;
```

These are two public fields. Ignore whether this is a good idea or not. How would you check the type of these fields and detect the presence or lack of this question mark?

Well, let's try the simple route:

```
Type nullable = GetType().GetField("Nullable").FieldType;
Type nonNullable = GetType().GetField("NonNullable").FieldType;
Console.WriteLine(ReferenceEquals(nullable, nonNullable));
```

Running this gives me:

```
True
```

So clearly this doesn't work. The `Type` objects are the exact same *instance*. They don't just *compare equal*, I got the same thing back, no difference. Basically, `FieldType` is oblivious to the presence or lack of this question mark.

My comments up above has some of those details but the main reason for this is at all existing nuget packages and compiled code will still work with this new support because of this. There is no need for any code to be rewritten to handle something like `NullableReferenceType<T>` suddenly. **This is a good thing**, but also means that you will still be passing null-references around and getting them back from existing nuget packages.

OK, so then, how would we detect this? The answer is that the information about the nullability is not attached to the type, as I mentioned above, but rather to the *thing* that has the type, in this case the fields.

Let's show attributes on these fields (again I'm using LINQPad):

```
GetType().GetField("Nullable").GetCustomAttributes().Dump();
GetType().GetField("NonNullable").GetCustomAttributes().Dump();
```

This gives this output:

[image: Nullable fields attributes]

As you can see here, the Nullable field has an additional attribute, `NullableAttribute`. I must confess that I do not know what that other attribute is about, I will have to investigate more.

This `NullableAttribute` attribute is much more complex than this simple example shows, as it has a collection property with `bool` values. Let's look at a slightly more complex example:

```
public List<string>? Nullable1;
public List<string?>? Nullable2;
```

Here, both fields are nullable references to a list, the difference is that I've said that one of the lists contains nullable references to strings, the other doesn't.

Here's some reflection to look at these collections:

```
GetType().GetField("Nullable1").GetCustomAttributesData().Dump();
GetType().GetField("Nullable2").GetCustomAttributesData().Dump();
```

and their output:

[image: nullable generic types]

Here you can see that there is a difference on the *second* element in this collection (I've "circled" them with red ... rectangles ...), I expect the first element applies to the list, the second one to the first generic type parameter. If you have generic lists containing generic types, the number of parameters will increase accordingly.

You can also find more information on this [excellent blog post by Rico Suter](https://blog.rsuter.com/the-output-of-nullable-reference-types-and-how-to-reflect-it/).

Comment: This also might be helpful: https://blog.rsuter.com/the-output-of-nullable-reference-types-and-how-to-reflect-it/

Comment: @Shoe Excellent, I couldn't remember the link or the name of that blogpost, but this is one of the articles I read when I learned about it. Have edited a mention into my answer.

Comment: A Microsoft employee (@333fred) linked me to https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/38087 to track the implementation of a reflection mechanism to solve the original problem.

Comment: As comments on the question may not last forever, your answer would be improve by making it fully standalone.

Comment: @IanRingrose Can you tell me what you had in mind? Do you mean that I should take out the use of LINQPad? Not sure what you you mean exactly by making it fully standalone. Please advise. Also, I'm on a cooling down break after the recent bruaha regarding firing of mods. I will be back in December provided more s**t hasn't hit the fan in the meantime. Feel free to edit my answer, or even to poach most of it and make your own if you have improvements in mind.